# USB boot flashes and crashes

Tags: boot, usb

I went through the steps listed on http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download but it does not work.  I start up my Toshiba Satellite laptop and press F12 to pull up the boot menu.  I select my USB drive and the screen goes black for a few seconds as if it is loading up.  There is a quick flash followed by a black screen for a few more seconds and finally ending with the system shutting down.  I can still access the BIOS and the boot menu, but I can no longer start up in Windows (system resume nor system recovery).

Edit: I'm not 100% positive but I believe this is my laptop model - http://www.toshibadirect.com/td/b2c/retail-product.jsp?poid=452488

Comment: Have you done the obvious? (Try redownloading and loading the image; use a different flashdrive)

Comment: What video card do you have ? Did you check the MD5 sum on the iso ?

Comment: bodhi - I'm not sure on the graphics card and I can't start up to look into that and I am not sure what I would be looking for in the md5sum file.  I looked at it but there isn't anything that jumps out at me as an error but I am no expert on this.

Comment: user606723 - I tried it once and I could still get into Windows after the boot failed.  After that first fail I re-did the steps outlined by the Ubuntu site and tried again.  After that I came to the situation I mentioned in the question.

Comment: bodhi - If I got my Toshiba Satellite series correct I believe the graphics card is from the ATI® Radeon™ 3100 series.  If you need other specs, I believe this is the correct laptop http://www.toshibadirect.com/td/b2c/retail-product.jsp?poid=452488

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a disc version of ubuntu and booted from the CD drive and it worked.  Maybe the files I got for USB were corrupt or incomplete somehow, I'm not sure.  Anyway, I got it working.